# Service Worker Registration issue

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Service Worker is not getting registered as I'm getting the error "a bad http response code 404 was received when fetching the script". What might be the step that I'm missing? I have registered service worker using:

```
<script>
    if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker
            .register('/ServiceWorker.js')
            .then(function() { console.log("Service Worker Registered"); });
    }
</script>
```

Also, can we cache an `.aspx` page in a service worker?

Answer (score 2):

This script inside the page is just unable to locate `/ServiceWorker.js` and could be due to 1 thing out of 2. Either the file `/ServiceWorker.js` does not exist in your root website folder or you mistyped the name. There's no missing step at all and the snippet looks ok.

The other question is yes, you can not only cache static files like fonts, CSS and JS, but also anything dynamic network response.

Inside `/ServiceWorker.js` add:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  console.log(event.request);
});
```

That will log in your browser console the URLs you are trying to request and you servers, images, text, etc.. and you can clone any response object and put it in your cache to be served from there on next visit.

Goog example / tutorials: https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker#serving_files_from_the_cache

Comment: That was helpful Zouhir. Thanks.

Comment: Also i want to ask how can we cache dynamic URL's in ServiceWorker.js file

Comment: No problem! Last part of my answer here highlights that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43950394/4412434

Comment: mistyped name and unable to locate the file is the same in the real world :)

Answer (score 0):

Check path of your `ServiceWorker.js` is accessible in your file to register serviceWorker. Other hand Which file you trying to fetch, that should be inside the scope of service worker.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/resources/ServiceWorker.js').then(function(registration) {
        // Registration was successful
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
        // registration failed :(
            console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
        });
    });
}
```

As above snippet can fetch:

`/resources/js/***.js  //200 Ok
/resources/css/***.css  //200 Ok 
/static/***.js  //404 Not found, because not in scope`

Answer (score 0):

Two things are possible:

- Either the path/name to **serviceWorker** file is not correct.
- ServiceWorker file is not present on the root of your folder structure.
  It should be present on the root.

Answer (score 0):

Using nrwl (Nx.js) you need to run nx build your_app.
It will create a public folder dist with the mockServiceWorker.js
then run : npm run msw dist
It will initialize to this folder to download stuff while service your app.